# Get all augments id and name from League of legends API

Tags: riot-games-api

Whats the endpoint for latest game Arena

"PlayerAugment1": 71,
"PlayerAugment2": 46,
"PlayerAugment3": 0,
"PlayerAugment4": 0,
"PlayerSubteamId": 1,

Want endpoint like
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/13.16.1/data/en_US/champion.json
i've tried https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/13.16.1/data/en_US/arenaAugments.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is not in data dragon.
You can find arena data here https://raw.communitydragon.org/13.16/cdragon/arena/en_us.json